# Get DNS MX records in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I want to get MX records for hostname www.example.com. Node has got function for it.

```
dns.resolveMx(domain, callback)
```

But i don't want that callback thingy. I want something like sync call. e.g.

```
var records = dns.resolveMx(domain);
```

Is this possible ?

(Note:- I found that function in Node documentation. link:- http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to block your application with a network operation? The DNS resolvers are called at the C level by the [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) library which is asynchronous by design. Therefore, you can't make it synchronous. This is the code from the DNS module with the unneeded parts removed:

```
var cares = process.binding('cares_wrap');

function resolver(bindingName) {
  var binding = cares[bindingName];

  return function query(name, callback) {
    callback = makeAsync(callback);
    var req = {
      bindingName: bindingName,
      callback: callback,
      oncomplete: onresolve
    };
    var err = binding(req, name);
    if (err) throw errnoException(err, bindingName);
    callback.immediately = true;
    return req;
  }
}

var resolveMap = {};
exports.resolveMx = resolveMap.MX = resolver('queryMx');
```

Comment: First thanks for the detailed explanation. Yes I want perform sync request, something like PHP function dns_get_record().

Comment: But do you have any reason for this? Putting everything into the function callback is more efficient than "pausing" your entire application for a DNS request.

Comment: Your point is valid. But you know I was porting one of the PHP libraries for Node. And it was suppose to work that way.

Comment: Node doesn't do _anything_ synchronously.  You have to get used to an entirely new way of thinking.

Answer (score 7):

Update 2021

There is now a `promises` submodule under `dns` module if some one is looking for sync calls.

Check more here

https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_class_dnspromises_resolver

```js
const dnsPromises = require('dns').promises;
const demo1 = await dnsPromises.resolveMx("gmail.com");
```